# Apply a shift function with different lead/lag offset to multiple columns in r

Tags: r, data.table, apply, plyr, lapply

I would like to apply the shift function in the data.table package to a data table containing 3 columns. This is what I have so far.

```
## Data table with 3 columns
df <- data.frame(X1 = c(0,0,1000,800,600,400,200), X2 = c(0,0,0,0,800,400,200), X3 = c(0,0,0,0,0,500,200))

#X1  X2  X3
#1    0   0   0
#2    0   0   0
#3 1000   0   0
#4  800   0   0
#5  600 800   0
#6  400 400 500
#7  200 200 200
```

First step is to locate the first non zero data (lead offset) in each column and store it in a dataframe to be used in "n" argument in the shift function. I used the following code;

```
num <- as.numeric(apply(df, 2, function(x) head(which(x!=0),1)))
```

I appended the values from the above function to the last row of the dt table

```
df <- rbind(df, num)
```

The goal is to run the shift function to all columns based on different leading offsets per column, as can be seen from the original table (i.e. nX1 = 3, nX2 = 5, nX3 = 6). I attempted this with the following code;

```
apply(df, 2, function(x, n) shift(x, n=n, fill=0, type="lead"), n = as.numeric(x[8, ]))
```

The above function applies all offset values to all columns instead of one lead offset per column. The desired table should look like this;

```
#  X1   X2  X3
#1 1000 800 500
#2 800  400 200
#3 600  200 0
#4 400  0   0
#5 200  0   0
#6 0    0   0
#7 0    0   0
```

I appreciate any help I can get on fixing my code.
 Thank you.

Comment: I don't follow this. Your `num` code gives `1/3/4` as a result, then you say it is `4/4/5` in your text. Take a look at `?Map` to iterative over each column of your dataset with a corresponding value to `shift` stored in `num`.

Comment: Something like `Map(function(v,l) shift(v,l,fill=0,type="lead"), df, lapply(df, function(x) which.max(x!=0)-2 ))`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I edited the num code. I tried your suggestion but got the following error: 

Error in shift(v, l, fill = 0, type = "lead") : 
  unused arguments (fill = 0, type = "lead")

Comment: thelatemail's solution worked for me. Are there other functions in your R environment with the same name that masked data.table's `shift`? Try `Map(function(v,l) data.table::shift(v,l,fill=0,type="lead"), df, lapply(df, function(x) which.max(x!=0)-1 )) %>% data.frame()` & see if that works for you. This version references `data.table::shift` explicitly. Also changed from `which.max(x!=0)-2` to `which.max(x!=0)-1` & converted the list back to data.frame at the end.

Comment: Your modification to thelatemail's original code works. Thanks again for your help.